# Why does sudo fail with strace?

Tags: linux, sudo, strace

I can run this command without issue.

```
/tmp $ sudo echo "hello world"
hello world
```

However, this command fails:

```
/tmp $ strace -o /tmp/out.log sudo echo "hello world"
sudo: effective uid is not 0, is /usr/bin/sudo on a file system with the 'nosuid' option set or an NFS file system without root privileges?
```

The origin of this error message is supposedly based on the file system configuration.

The question boils down to, how does strace influence sudo such that some nosuid file system becomes relevant?

The current working directory is /tmp.

```
/tmp $ df .
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/tmpn1p1 101584140 60379868  41187888  60% /
/tmp $ mount | grep tmpn1p1
/dev/tmpn1p1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,discard,data=ordered)
```

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` must be run as `root`, and it uses the Set UID bit to achieve this (the `---s------`, or the `0o4000` in octal, shown below). With the bit set, the program is always executed as if the owning user had run it, instead of the currently logged in user.

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/sudo
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 149080 Jan 31  2020 /usr/bin/sudo
$ stat -c '%a' /usr/bin/sudo
4755
```

As you're running `sudo` via `strace`, you'll probably find that `strace` will call a variant of `exec()`, and won't respect the Set UID bit, and thus `sudo` isn't running as `root`:

```
$ strace -e execve sudo echo "hello world"
execve("/usr/bin/sudo", ["sudo", "echo", "hello world"], 0x7fffc171e2e0 /* 36 vars */) = 0
sudo: effective uid is not 0, is /usr/bin/sudo on a file system with the 'nosuid' option set or an NFS file system without root privileges?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Inverting the order of `strace` and `sudo` will do what you want though, so long as you're not trying to inspect the operation of `sudo` itself:

```
$ sudo strace -e execve echo "hello world"
[sudo] password for attie:
execve("/bin/echo", ["echo", "hello world"], 0x7ffc300dbb28 /* 17 vars */) = 0
hello world
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

---

The root issue here is that `strace` will attach to the process (much like a debugger) using [`ptrace()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace), and in this state, it is not possible to obey the Set UID bit without presenting a security issue.

The same thing happens when running under `gdb`:

```
$ gdb sudo -ex 'run echo "hello world"' -ex quit
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 8.1-0ubuntu3.2) 8.1.0.20180409-git
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from sudo...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Starting program: /usr/bin/sudo echo "hello world"
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
sudo: effective uid is not 0, is /usr/bin/sudo on a file system with the 'nosuid' option set or an NFS file system without root privileges?
[Inferior 1 (process 27480) exited with code 01]
```

Comment: Do you have any documentation on your claim "*...and in this state, it is not possible to obey the Set UID bit without presenting a security issue.*"? :)

Comment: The issue is that the by using `ptrace()`, user is now able to influence the execution of the program - by altering memory, etc... If you were to obey SUID, _and_ permit `ptrace()`, then the user gets control over a process running as some other user (possibly even root).

Comment: Yea, but isn’t that normal behavior? Unless you have `ptrace` capability, you can’t `ptrace` other users’ processes. I wonder whether “other user” means different RUID or EUID?